# BigQuery Scenario for usage

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working on one of the usecase where one part of scenario, I am not able to achieve , where  I need to calculate new_tarif_allownce based on the mobile data usage for the prepaid mobile data of the subscriber.

| subscriber_no | bill_start_date | bill_end_date | gift_given | gift_received | ROW_NO | Data_allowed | new_tarif_allownace |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 01-Jan-20 | 05-Jan-20 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 111 | 01-Jan-20 | 05-Jan-20 | 100 | 0 | 2 | 1000 | 900 |
| 111 | 01-Jan-20 | 05-Jan-20 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1000 | 900 |
| 111 | 01-Jan-20 | 05-Jan-20 | 200 | 0 | 4 | 1000 | 700 |
| 111 | 01-Jan-20 | 05-Jan-20 | 0 | 50 | 5 | 1000 | 750 |
| 111 | 01-Jan-20 | 05-Jan-20 | 100 | 300 | 6 | 1000 | 950 |
| 111 | 01-Jan-20 | 05-Jan-20 | 0 | 700 | 7 | 1000 | 1650 |
| 222 | 01-feb-20 | 05-feb-20 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 222 | 01-feb-20 | 05-feb-20 | 100 | 0 | 2 | 2000 | 1900 |

**Please find the details:**

1. Given fields: subscriber_no, bill_start_date ,bill_end_date  , gift_given    ,gift_received , Data_allowed
2. Derived fields:

   - ROW_NO  = row_number () over ( )  as ROW_NO
   - new_tarif_allownace = Data_allowed - gift_given + gift_received
3. Note to the point: If the columns have data as `gift_given=0` or `gift_received=0` that mean there is no calculation required for the column new_tarif_allownace, but we need to populate the previous/last calculated value as main in this rows
4. Logic I used to maintain the calculation with calculation but seems its not working:

```
case when last_gift_given<>0  
     Then min( TARIFF_ALLOWANCE_DATA_MB  
             - IFNULL(gift_given,0) 
             + IFNULL(gift_received,0 ) ) over (order by ROW_NO ASC 
                                                rows unbounded preceding)
     else max( TARIFF_ALLOWANCE_DATA_MB  
             - IFNULL(gift_given,0)
             + IFNULL(gift_received,0 ) ) over (order by ROW_NO ASC 
                                                rows unbounded preceding)
END as new_tarif_allownace_data,
```

Need the bigquery which do the calculation along with maintaing previous data If there is no change in
gift_given & gift_received columns.

I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8cNU.png) of the data as well for clear visibility.

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output, corresponding to the sample input table you've shared?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear to me, but I think you are probably looking for something like

```
data_allowed 
  - sum(gift_given) OVER (PARTITION BY subscriber_no ORDER BY row_no)
  + sum(gift_received) OVER (PARTITION BY subscriber_no ORDER BY row_no) new_tarif_allownace_data
```

You can see the basic idea [in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0YL8Bm9X) (not BigQuery, but should work the same).

I wouldn't worry about a special case for when one of the values is 0. The addition or subtraction of 0 won't hurt anything, so it seems safe to use. You can still wrap your values in `ifnull` if you want, but I don't think it's necessary when doing it this way.

Based on your current SQL, I think you might be trying to do this in a recursive CTE. It's certainly possible to do that if the above doesn't meet your needs, but it's not clear to me from your post whether/why that is necessary/preferred.

Comment: for eg: if subscriber=111 gave some amount as a donar to someone with his allowed_allowance =100GB , he gave 90GB as a gift then his new_allowance = 100-90 = 10GB in  day1, but at day2 , he didnt donate or receive any amount then his amount would be still 10GB in day2 , but in day3 he received some amount as a gift 10GB , then his new  new_allowance = 10 +10 =20 GB in day3...so we have to maintain the previous day data in the day2(in second row), if there is no changes in his allowance.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why that isn't just the sum of the previous amounts. As you can see in the Fiddle, this correctly calculates the `new_tarif_allownace` from the other columns in your table. If that's not what you want, please edit your question to include some sample data (including the case where what I suggested above doesn't work) and expected output.